# Как разработать пакетный файл

Tags: cmd

Как разработать пакетный файл для вывода информации в файл обо всех имеющихся исполняемых файлах в заданном директории? Директорий (полный путь) задается в командной строке.

Answer (score 2):

Берете и разрабатываете.

Во-первых, нужно определиться что за пакетный файл. Обычно это скрипт с расширением BAT или CMD, которые выполняет коммандный процессор CMD.EXE.

Во-вторых, нужно разработать алгоритм. Понятно, что нужно для начала получить список файлов. А затем по нему пройтись и получить информацию по каждому.

В третьих, Вам следует попробовать использовать следующие конструкции:

```
DIR *.EXE
REM получить список файлов с расширением EXE и вывести основные параметры файлов
FOR %A IN (*.EXE) DO ECHO %A
REM выводит имя каждого файла с расширением EXE в текущем каталоге.
REM вместо ECHO можно подставить свою команду, которая будет применена к каждому файлу
```

Answer (score 0):

В cmd исполняться (точнее будут кандидатами на исполнение) файлы, расширения которых перечислены через ';' в переменной PATHEXT.

echo %PATHEXT% выведет эту строку. Вот отсюда и танцуйте.

Comment: Комментарий: c:\\windows и c:\\windows\\system32, где c:\\windows - каталог, куда установлена ОСь, по умолчанию прописаны в PATH. Regedit'ы живут именно там. Для выполнения остальных исполняемых файлов нужно задавать или абсолютный путь, или относительный путь относительно текущего каталога. Сорри, за тавтологию.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd\windows\system32

dir *.exe /P

pause
```

Где в первой строке прописываете нужный Вам путь, `/P` означает пауза после каждого просмотра экрана. Можете использовать для `dir` параметр `/W`, т.е. вывоз только имён файлов в несколько столбцов. Для остальных параметров введите `DIR /?`.